# Adding the sum of checkboxes appending instead of adding

Tags: javascript

What i am trying to do in my form is, when a user clicks on certain checkboxes, the value (in float form) is added up to a sum, but the way my code is now it appends instead of adds.

This is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function updateSum() {
      var total = "0.00";
      $(".sum:checked").each(function(i, n) { total += parseFloat($(n).val()).toFixed(2); })
      $("#total").val(total);
    }
    // run the update on every checkbox change and on startup
    $("input.sum").change(updateSum);
    updateSum();
})
</script>
```

When i check multiple boxes i get: **1.002.003.00** instead of: **6.00**

my code looks right i cannot see what i have missed. Any advice on the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Do the math with numbers first...then use `toFixed()` for final display only

Comment: [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed#Syntax) returns a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see a quick example how `toFixed()` behaves and how should you add floats in JavaScript if you have the original value as a string:

```js
(function() {
   var total = '0.00';

   for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      total = (parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(4.3)).toFixed(2);
   }

   console.log('total', {
      total: total,
      typeOfTotal: typeof(total)
   });
})();
```

Based on the below example you can see that `toFixed()` returns a string so I suggest to modify to your code to the following in order to add numbers properly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function updateSum() {
      var total = "0.00";
      $(".sum:checked").each(function(i, n) {
         let sum = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat($(n).val());
         total = sum.toFixed(2);
      });
      $("#total").val(total);
    }
    // run the update on every checkbox change and on startup
    $("input.sum").change(updateSum);
    updateSum();
});
```

You can read further about [Number.prototype.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) and [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) here.

Comment: Thank you! so it returns a string! i see, noted for the future, thank you again :)

Comment: Why you have `total = '0.00'` ? even though you're using it for numeric calculation ? it should be number mate

Comment: It was in the question in that way because I assume the value is coming from HTML so I wanted to represent a code which behaves similarly like in the question's example but I totally agree with you about the calculation part.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change your total= '0.00' to number( total = 0.00 ) instead of string.
2. toFixed returns string not numbers

```js
let x = 1.22

console.log(typeof (1.22).toFixed(2))
```